# Inserting an element at the end of the list in C

Tags: c

In the program below I try to insert the elements at the end of the list and print them out. However I get a Segmentation fault at if(headp->next == NULL). What am I doing wrong ? Any suggestions? Thank you!

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    /* these arrays are just used to give the parameters to 'insert',
       to create the 'people' array 
    */

    #define HOW_MANY 7
    char *names[HOW_MANY]= {"Simon", "Suzie", "Alfred", "Chip", "John", "Tim",
                  "Harriet"};
    int ages[HOW_MANY]= {22, 24, 106, 6, 18, 32, 24};

    typedef struct person
    {
      char *name;
      int age;
      struct person *next;
    }Person;
    static Person* insert_end(Person *headp, char *name, int age) 
    {
      Person *p = malloc(sizeof(Person)); 
      if (p == NULL)
        abort();
      p->name = name;
      p->age = age;
      if (headp->next == NULL)
      {
        headp->next = p;
        return p;
      }
      else
      {
        Person *current = headp;
        while(current->next != NULL)
        {
          current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = p;
        return p;
      }

    }  
    int main(int argc, char **argv) 
    {
     Person *people1 = NULL;
     for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
      {
        people1 = insert_end(people1, names[i], ages[i]);
      }
    while(people1 != NULL)
      {
        printf ("name: %s, age: %i\n", people1->name, people1->age);
        people1 = people1->next;
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Run your code under a debugger.

Comment: Run it in a debugger and you'll see

Comment: ask yourself: the first element (people1) is null but it's next does it even have a next? when the header was allocated?(answer: never), start by making sure your first item is allocated and then move on

Answer (score 0):

Initially when the list is empty then `headp` is equal to `NULL`.

Thus these statements

```
if (headp->next == NULL)
```

and

```
while(current->next != NULL)
```

result in undefined behavior.

Also you forgot to initialize to NULL the data member `next` of the appended node.

The function can be written more simpler

```
static int insert_end( Person **headp, char *name, int age ) 
{
    Person *p = malloc( sizeof( Person ) ); 
    int success = p != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        p->name = name;
        p->age  = age;
        p->next = NULL;

        wjile ( *headp ) headp = &( *headp )->next; 

        *headp = p;
    }

    return success;
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
size_t i = 0;

while ( i < sizeof( names ) / sizeof( *names ) && 
        insert_end( &people1, names[i], ages[i] ) ) i++
```